# Example of $f: \mathbb{S}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}\subset \mathbb{R}, $ $\mathbb{S}$ closed with no fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

This is a textbook question.

"A function $f: \mathbb{S}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}\subset \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{S}$ closed is called **weakly contractive** if 
 \begin{align*}
 d(f(x), f(y))<d(x, y)\qquad \forall x,y\in \mathbb{S}
 \end{align*} 
 Given an example of a weakly contractive mapping with no fixed point. Show that if $\mathbb{S}$ is compact, then $f$ has a fixed point. (Hint: Define $g(x)=|f(x)-x|$ and check its extreme value property on $\mathbb{S}$)"

Question?

Is the definition of weakly contractive correct/standard or should it be a $\leq$ symbol instead of $<$? (textbook, although good, does have some math typos)

IF it was $\leq$ then if $\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{R}_+$ and $f(x)=x+c, c>0$ could be a solution.

If it is indeed $<$ then I have no idea how to proceed. Any suggestions?

EDIT: perhaps $f(x)=-1/x$ could do it even with the strict inequality? (the idea here being exploiting $\mathbb{S}$ closed but not compact) Is that right?
EDIT2: Just realized this does not work. $f(x)=-1/x$ is not defined at $x=0$. Making $\mathbb{S}$ not closed.
EDIT3: There was a hint for the question, just added now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the definition is correct. The point is that for the contraction mapping theorem to hold, it's not enough to say "points get closer when you map them under $f$". You need them to get closer by some factor $\lambda<1$ that does not depend on the points you plug in.

By the contraction mapping theorem, $f$ *will* have a fixed point if there exists $\lambda<1$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))<\lambda d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in S$. So this tells you that no such $\lambda$ can exist for your $f$. In other words, for any $\lambda<1$, there exist $x,y \in S$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \geq \lambda d(x,y)$.

I think you'll find that Ross Millikan's function does the trick, since as $x,y \to \infty$, $d(f(x),f(y)) \approx d(x,y)$. To show that the inequality holds, suppose $x<y$, so $e^{-x}>e^{-y}$. Also note that by the choice of $S$, $f$ is increasing on $S$, so $x+e^{-x}<y+e^{-y}$. Then:
$$d(f(x),f(y)) = (y+e^{-y})-(x+e^{-x}) = (y-x)+ (e^{-y}-e^{-x})<(y-x)=d(x,y).$$

Answer (score 1):

The adjective weakly would suggest that $\le$ is appropriate.  I do not know what is standard.   Your answer would be a good one in that case.  Without the $\le$ you need to push things off to infinity like your $+c$ does, but still have a contraction.  How about $x \to x+e^{-x}$ on $x \ge 1$?

Comment: The "weak" refers to the fact that the RHS is just $d(x,y)$ and not $\lambda d(x,y)$ for some constant $\lambda<1$.

Comment: I was thinking about some sort of asymptotic function approaching f(x)=x from above. But that invalidates the inequality for small values of x, no?

Comment: @LucasMation:  Not necessarily.  That is why I chose $x \ge 1$ for $S$, so the derivative would be strictly less than $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: @LucasMation:  No, at $x=1$ we have $f'(x)=1-\frac 1e$